# How to disable Internet Explorer Startup settings via regedit? (Not Homepage)

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, registry

I need to **disable** Internet Explorer Startup settings. How can I do this via regedit?

[image: This image is what I'm talking about]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following steps to enable/disable Start Internet Explorer with tabs from last browsing session option.

1. Open Run window and type "regedit" to open registry editor.
2. Navigate to location below.

   > Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ContinuousBrowsing
3. Find the "Enabled" registry key.
4. Double click on it and set its value. (To disable : 0, To enable : 1)
5. Click on OK to close the dialog.
6. Restart Internet Explorer to take effect of changes.

The screenshot as below:

[image]

Note: If you disable the "Start with tabs from the last session" option, it will auto enable the "Start with home page" option. There is no way to disable both of them at the same time.

Comment: I applied your answer before. But it changes only state of the ContinuousBrowsing option (chekced or unchecked). Does not disable it.

Comment: There is no way to disable the startup, we could only select one of them (using "Start with tabs from the last session" or using "Start with home page")